# Type-safely decorate object with metadata

Tags: c#, generics, types, generic-programming

I have certain entities (classes). Each entity can have metadata associated with it. An entity can only have at most one metadata object of each type.

Simplified example:

```cs
// Approach 1

public interface Entity {} 
public interface MetadataBase {}

public sealed class EntityPrice : MetadataBase {
    public int Price{ get; }
    public Price(int price) => Price = price;
}

public sealed class EntityAmount : MetadataBase {
    public int Amount { get; }
    public EntityAmount(int amount) => Amount = amount;
}

// somewhere in user code
Entity someEntity;
MetadataManager.Associate(someEntity, new EntityPrice(13));
MetadataManager.Associate(someEntity, new EntityAmount(17));

// somewhere else later
var price = MetadataManager.Get<EntityPrice>(someEntity).Price; 
var amount = MetadataManager.Get<EntityAmount>(someEntity).Amount;
```

The alternative is to have the concrete entity class implement a lot of interfaces (one for each use-case). Every entity class would grow rather large rather quickly and violate some SOLID principles:

```cs
// Approach 2 (I do not want this)

public interface Entity {} 

public interface WithPrice : Entity { 
    int Price { get; }
}

public interface WithAmount : Entity { 
    int Amount { get; }
}

public interface ConcreteEntity : WithPrice, WithAmount { }

// somewhere in code
ConcreteEntity entity;
var price = entity.Price;
var amount = entity.Amount;
```

However, approach 2 has a major advantage: It is well-typed.

Consider the following method that requires both Id and Amount for the two approaches (note that an `Entity` reference does not necessarily have a price or amount associated with it):

```cs
// Approach 1
public static int CalculateTotal(Entity entity) {
    var amount = MetadataManager.Get<EntityAmount>(entity).Amount;
    var price = MetadataManager.Get<EntityPrice>(entity).Price;
    return amount * price; 
}

// Approach 2
public static int CalculateTotal<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : WithAmount, WithPrice {
    return entity.Amount * entity.Price;
}
```

Decoupling with metadata trades type-safety for flexibility. `CalculateTotal` for approach 1 throws during runtime when the metadata is not present, whereas approach 2 fails during compilation.

**I want a way to use approach 1 but still have type-safe method parameters.**

I tried this approach:

```cs
public interface WithMetadata<out TMetadata> {
    Entity Entity { get; }
    TMetadata Metadata { get; }
}
```

**How do I extend this for two or more metadata objects, so that I can implement `CalculateTotal` with a type-safe parameter? How do I extract the appropriately typed metadata elegantly?**

Edit: I just realized that I can implement `CalculateTotal` with generic type constraints. But what if I wanted to save a **list of entities with both metadata objects** so that I can calculate prices later? What's the type of that list?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite get what you want to do here? Can't you just have an entity with Amount and Price in it? You need them both to calculate your total as you are only passing one entity to the Calculate class...

Comment: @Isma I want the calculate method to work for *all* entities that happen to have an amount and price. That's also just a minimal example, because my actual use-case is a lot more complex.

Comment: So some entities might have a price, others might only have the amount and some might have both? Maybe something like Python would be a better fit for this....

Comment: @Isma exactly! And some may have other data for other use-cases as well.

Comment: Does it have to be in C#? You could do this with mixins in Python

Comment: @Isma sadly yes. I'd love to have mixins, they really fit the problem well.

Comment: wouldnt it be easier to use `TryCalculateTotal` which in turn returns a bool indicating success and returns it's calculated value in an out parameter?

Comment: @Thomas I intentionally left out nice-to-have things like `Try` methods for the example. Adding that doesn't solve the problem: The check would still be during runtime. I want compile time safety. But I agree, `Try` is much nicer than catching a potential exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using composition and some interfaces:

```
public interface IMetadata
{
}

public interface IMetadataWithType<TMetadata> where TMetadata : struct
{
    TMetadata Value { get; }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    List<IMetadata> Metadata { get; }
}

public abstract class MetadataBase<TMetadata> : IMetadata, IMetadataWithType<TMetadata> where TMetadata : struct
{
    protected MetadataBase(TMetadata value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public TMetadata Value { get; private set; }
}

public class PriceMetadata : MetadataBase<decimal>
{
    public PriceMetadata(decimal value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public class AmountMetadata : MetadataBase<int>
{
    public AmountMetadata(int value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public class EntityWithAmount : IEntity
{
    public EntityWithAmount()
    {
        Metadata.Add(new AmountMetadata(10));
    }

    public List<IMetadata> Metadata { get; } = new List<IMetadata>();
}

public class EntityWithPrice : IEntity
{
    public EntityWithPrice()
    {
        Metadata.Add(new PriceMetadata(199));
    }

    public List<IMetadata> Metadata { get; } = new List<IMetadata>();
}

public class EntityWithPriceAndAmount : IEntity
{
    public EntityWithPriceAndAmount()
    {
        Metadata.Add(new PriceMetadata(199));
        Metadata.Add(new AmountMetadata(10));
    }

    public List<IMetadata> Metadata { get; } = new List<IMetadata>();
}

public static class Calculator
{
    public static void Total(IEntity entity)
    {
        int? amount = null;
        decimal? price = null;
        foreach(var metadata in entity.Metadata)
        {
            if (metadata is PriceMetadata priceMetadata)
                price = priceMetadata.Value;
            else if (metadata is AmountMetadata amountMetadata)
                amount = amountMetadata.Value;
        }

        if (amount.HasValue && price.HasValue)
            Console.WriteLine($"Total: {amount.Value * price.Value}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Entity does not have price and amount metadata");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var entityWithPrice = new EntityWithPrice();
        var entityWithAmount = new EntityWithAmount();
        var entityWithPriceAndAmount = new EntityWithPriceAndAmount();
        Calculator.Total(entityWithPrice);
        Calculator.Total(entityWithAmount);
        Calculator.Total(entityWithPriceAndAmount);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Entity does not have price and amount metadata
Entity does not have price and amount metadata
Total: 1990
```

You could also try to achieve this using the [dynamic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic), reflection (for example adding attributes to the classes to indicate what they do) and extension methods or a combination of these techniques, but I think the approach above is quite clean, if you want to have reference types as possible values for your metadata remove the struct constraint.

Comment: This is a clean solution to the base problem, but not what I am looking for. I'd like `Calculator.Total` to not compile when the passed entity does not have either metadata. E.g the call `Calculator.Total(entityWithPrice)` should fail to compile at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Whey did you add the `: struct` constraint?

Comment: You can't have dynamic types and compilation checks at the same time, or at least not easyly, not sure if it's worth the hussle. Make a good set of unit tests and keep ur code simple.